# Issue updating Ubuntu from 14.04.6 LTS to 16.04.6 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I'm actually doing an internship in a company, so they asked me to update their Ubuntu before starting my job. The problem is that when I do the "`do-release-upgrade`", I've got an error message and system recovery to the original. Then I checked in the main.log and I have those lines:

```
2019-07-03 09:34:48,879 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.trusty']'
2019-07-03 09:34:48,879 INFO uname information: 'Linux AWARE 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64'
2019-07-03 09:34:49,431 INFO apt version: '1.0.1ubuntu2.23'
2019-07-03 09:34:49,431 INFO python version: '3.4.3 (default, Nov 12 2018, 22:25:49)
[GCC 4.8.4]'
2019-07-03 09:34:49,436 INFO release-upgrader version '16.04.26' started
2019-07-03 09:34:49,445 INFO locale: 'fr_FR' 'UTF-8'
2019-07-03 09:34:49,459 DEBUG screen returned: 'No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root. 2019-07-03 09:34:49,460 INFO re-exec inside screen: '['screen', '-e', '\\0\\0', '-L', '-c', 'screenrc', '-S', 'ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window', '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-p0eywysq/xenial', '--mode=server', '--frontend=DistUpgradeViewText']'
```

Comment: Why have you tagged 12.04 & 14.04?    I also see mention of 14.04 & 14.10 (3.16) kernel versions mentioned in messages, which implies your system is not built from standard repos, has packages held or other things done to it.  I'd suggest pulling it back to standard repositories/software only as that's what is tested & known to work.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry it's my first time here. Yes my system is a clone of the original one because I have to create a new version of their app so for that I have to update to ubuntu 16 because the app can only be run under it, so how am I suppose to do that without the access to the original repos  ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16?  Is this a IoT applicance (ie. you mean Ubuntu Core 16) I don't know what original repos you mean?  If you mean Ubuntu repos, after a releases reaches EOL it's repo is moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`  (no country mirrors though so they also need removal) which can be done via `sed` quickly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1155600/edit) your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `do-release-upgrade`